# redefine $susy values at breakpoint container

Tags: containers, breakpoints, susy-compass

I am trying to redefine the $susy property container within a media query.  I'm trying to run

```
@include breakpoint($mobile) {

  $susy: (
   container: 100%,
  );
}
```

when i compile cmd says try using $susy: (container: 100%)!global instead--- i tried that and it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, $susy is the global setting in which you set up your site's basic layout. For subsequent layouts at breakpoints, I would use new maps, e.g. $tablet, $desktop.

Answer (score 0):

`$susy` is a global setting, and Sass doesn't scope variable changes to media contexts. You can do what @user2713715 suggests, and give other layouts new names, but Susy also has a tool to help apply those settings to different code blocks. The most basic is `with-layout`:

```
@include breakpoint($mobile) {
  @include with-layout(100%) { // can pass in shorthand, or a map of new settings
    // any code in here will use the new layout...
  }
}
```

But, if you are using breakpoint, we have an even better shortcut:

```
@include susy-breakpoint($mobile, (container: 100%)) {
  // again: you can use the shorthand or a settings map.
  // any code in here will use the new layout...
}
```